# How do I return all data for the previous month in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I return all data for the previous month in SQL. (NOT SQL SERVER). This is the code I have.

```
SELECT     DOD
FROM       ZZZ_DEPARTURE_DATES
WHERE      DOD = (MONTH, -1, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data so it's easier for people to understand what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Oracle:

```
SELECT     DOD
FROM       ZZZ_DEPARTURE_DATES
WHERE      DOD >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'MON')
AND        DOD < TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON');
```

Note: using this syntax is more likely to take advantage of an index on `DOD`, if one exists.